# Ansible: Quotes around ip derived from group_vars

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, ansible-template

I'm using Ansible to upgrade to Elastisearch 7.13 and I need to make some changes to my `elasticsearch.yml` and having issues working out the syntax.

I have a file (elasticsearch.yml) under group_vars as follows:

```yaml
elastisearch_ips: "{{ groups['elasticsearch'] | map('quote') | map ('extract','hostvars', ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(', ') }}'
```

and under my templates folder I have a template file for elasticsearch which includes the line that I need changed:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ {{ elasticsearch_ips }} ]
```

Once the file is deployed the string looks like this:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3 ]
```

However, I need the string to look like this:

```
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: [ "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3" ]
```

Not sure how to add the quotes correctly, I have tried several things but nothing obtained the desired results.

Comment: => `elastisearch_ips: "\"{{ groups['elasticsearch'] | map ('extract','hostvars', ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join('\", \"') }}\"'`

Comment: That works thanks, just add to change the last \"' to a \""

Comment: I actually copy/pasted  your own example which suffers from the same syntax error before making the required changes.

Comment: for consideration, since yaml is a superset of JSON, make jinja2 responsible for the entire value and serialize the list of strings to a JSON array: `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: {{ groups... | map(...) | list | to_json }}` and end up with less backslashery